# I removed all the working directory files, including .git directory but I have a copy on github

Tags: git, github

I unfortunately deleted, using a bash script, all the directories (including .git) from my working directory.

Now, I have a copy on github. This copy was a "push" from this project. How can I retrieve all the files, log, and git functionality to my local directory ?

Is it as simple as creating a new folder, starting git and downloading the project from Github? I would like to maintain everything as this never happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. If you just `git clone <yourProject>` into a new (or the same) directory, you’ll have your project’ state locally and can work with it as if you never deleted anyting. This is a common thing to do if you messed up your local copy, cf. [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1597/) for amusement.